# Make a copy of a part of a database with foreignkeys in django

Tags: django

I have a number of objects on a yearly basis and want to copy one of them to a new year, with appropriate foreignkeys. The model Realisations below link to a number of Moments, and when I make a new copy I want to "keep" the connection between the new Moment and the new Realisation.

Based on what I have found on the Internet I am working on the following piece of code:

```
realis_lista = Realisering.objects.filter(year=thisyear).all()
for obj in realis_lista:
    new_obj = obj
    moment = Moment.objects.filter(realisering__pk=obj.pk).all()
    new_obj.pk = None
    new_obj.year = nextyear
    new_obj.save()

    if moment:
        for mom in moment:
            new_mom = mom
            new_mom.pk = None
            new_mom.realisation = ??new_obj??
```

What should the last row be? I need to find where new_obj was saved (its pk), but the only idea I have is to use something like

```
n_obj = 
Realisering.objects.filter(year=nextyear).filter(period=obj.period)....    
new_mom.realisation=n_obj
```

But there must be a better way.

Maybe there is an altogether better way to make this copy?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather:

- Your Moment model has a Foreign Key to the Realisation model.
- You take all your Realisations from the year `thisyear` and create a copy for each of them, with a new year `nextyear`.
- For every Realisation you make a copy of the Moment associated with it (if any), and you want to assign the newyear copy of Realisation to this copy of the Moment.

From what I can see, you don't need to search where `new_obj` was saved, you've got it right there in your code.

I think you should try

```
for obj in Realisering.objects.filter(year=thisyear).all():
    # .first() will return None if it doesn't find it
    moment = Moment.objects.filter(realisering__pk=obj.pk).first() 
    obj.year = nextyear
    # The my_object.pk = None and my_object.save() combinaison will generate a new instance
    obj.pk = None
    obj.save()
    # obj is now the copy of the object

    if moment:
        moment.pk = None
        # We assign the Realisation copy to the Moment copy
        moment.realisation = obj
        moment.save()
```

Note that if your model uses inheritance, ManyToMany fields or OneToOne fields, additional precautions must be taken: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

Comment: Thanks, but I thought I had tested that. I used moment.realisation.pk = obj.pk, but obj.pk was None. So what you are saying is that when I save obj, it get assigned a pk without me looking into the database? That should have worked for me as well, should it not?